# Highchart - Unable to parse my JSON string as a variable in the series but hardcoded way seems to work fine

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to create a highchart based on dynamic data in my Javascript file. I have created a function called dynamicHighchart and it is parsing in JSON 'myJsonString'

The below works fine which is what I got from the console log:

```
series: [{ "name": "Oct 20", "type": "line", "data": [24025, 24200, 24075, 23925, 23950, 23850, 23650] }, { "name": "Nov 20", "type": "line", "data": [18875, 19125, 18125, 17650, 17500, 16375, 14725, 16625, null, 15550, 14875, 14900, 14925, 15450, 16125, 14500, 13375, 14150, 14150, 12900, 12600, 12950, 13200, 13125, 13175, 13000, 13100, 13100, 13150] }]
```

but doing this doesn't work - shows as an empty chart:

```
series: myJsonString
```

The way I got my stringify JSON is using the following line of code:
myJsonString = JSON.stringify(arr);

Am I parsing myJSON variable in correctly to the series?

My highchart function:

```
function dynamicHighchart(myJsonString) {

    console.log(myJsonString);

        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

            chart: {
            renderTo: 'chart1div',
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Chart Title'
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                enabled: true,
                text: 'X axis title'
            },
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Y axis title'
            }
            },
            series: myJsonString
            //series: [{ "name": "Oct 20", "type": "line", "data": [24025, 24200, 24075, 23925, 23950, 23850, 23650] }, { "name": "Nov 20", "type": "line", "data": [18875, 19125, 18125, 17650, 17500, 16375, 14725, 16625, null, 15550, 14875, 14900, 14925, 15450, 16125, 14500, 13375, 14150, 14150, 12900, 12600, 12950, 13200, 13125, 13175, 13000, 13100, 13100, 13150] }]
    });
}
```

Comment: and without `JSON.stringify(arr)`, by passing your arr directly to series?

Comment: Oh yeah that works! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse your data from string to an array:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: JSON.parse(myJsonString),
    ...
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/c562p8mj/